# Python_Display df through function

Tags: python, function, dataframe, printing, jupyter-notebook

I'm using notebook in Google Colaboratory
When I print df using this snippet of code:

```
calls.head()
```

Output looks nice

[image: Output looks nice]

In my code I need to make def for multiple dfs, so when I'm using the same code:

```
df_list = [calls, inter, tar, users]
for df in df_list:
  print(df.head())
```

BTW, I have no idea why I need to add `print` here, otherwise it's not working.

So my output looks like that:

[image: Not nice]

How to make it look like in the first picture?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays I've found this solution with using `display`:

```
 from IPython.display import display
    
 df_list = [users, calls, inter, tar]
 for df in df_list:
    display(df.head())
```

[image: Nice view]

Comment: In case smbd knows method how to do it within `print`, pls, leave comments below